# How to accumulate seriesPoints in XtraReport BarChart?

Tags: c#, datatable, devexpress, bar-chart, xtrareport

I have a DataTable which contains a column with different years values, and a DevExpress XtraReport bar chart that prints a value for each year. At runtime, I'm creating the seriesPoint like this :

```
foreach (DataRow row in listEcheances.Rows)
    { 
        string expr = String.Format("ECHEANCE = #{0}#", echeDate.ToString(DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
        int nbRowsEcheance = DtData.Select(expr).Length;
        seriesEcheance.Points.Add(new SeriesPoint(Convert.ToDateTime(row    ["ECHEANCE"]).Year, nbRowsEcheance));
    }
```

The bar chart doesn't accumulate values for each year. I don't know how to say it to the chart. Does someone can help me ?

Thank's